# How can i delete html tags using php with preg_replace function

Tags: php, html

im using php and i wanna know how to delete this html tags `<div><p></p></div>`

from this:

```
<div class="xxx" height="xxx" width="xxx">
    <iframe allowfullscreen="" class="xxx" frameborder="x" height="xxx" src="xxx" width="xxx"></iframe>
    <p height="xxx" width="xxx">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" class="xxx" frameborder="x" height="xxx" src="xxx" width="xxx"></iframe>
```

i just wanna delete tags `<div><p></p></div>` when `<div><iframe><p></p></div>`

i've tried using preg_replace(); function

```
$html = preg_replace("'(<div[^>]*>)([^<]*<iframe[^>]*>[^<]*</iframe>[^<]*)(<p[^>]*>)(</p>)(</div>)'sim", "$2", $html);
```

but i cant get it could you please help me, thanks

Comment: Don't use regexp to process HTML. Use a DOM parser library like `DOMDocument`.

Comment: I guess I should link to this before someone else does http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1301076

Comment: hi @Barmar i use DOMDocument like this:

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($selector->query('//div[contains(attribute::class, "media_embed")]') as $e ) {
    $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);

but that delete all, i just wanna delete <div><p></p></div>

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments. Edit the question.

Comment: I think `//contains` matches contents at any depth, so it will remove the top-level DIV because `media_embed` is somewhere in it.

Comment: And to do what you want, you need to save the `iframe` element in a variable, remove the DIV that contains it, and then add the iframe back as a child of the parent DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply [strip tags](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php)?

```
$string = '<div class="xxx" height="xxx" width="xxx"><iframe allowfullscreen="" class="xxx" frameborder="x" height="xxx" src="xxx" width="xxx"></iframe><p height="xxx" width="xxx">&nbsp;</p></div>';
$newstring = strip_tags($string, '<iframe>');  
echo $newstring;

// This will output:
<iframe allowfullscreen="" class="xxx" frameborder="x" height="xxx" src="xxx" width="xxx"></iframe><p height="xxx" width="xxx">&nbsp;
```

Comment: That will remove all tags, so he won't get the `<iframe>` tag that he wants.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't noticed that, but I just corrected it.

Comment: yes he's right and i have a lot of html tags with that i delete the other html tags

Comment: The second parameter of strip_tags receives a string with the tags allowed... in this case it is only <iframe> but you can add more, like '<iframe><a><em>' and so on.